# Putting x axis text closer to barplot bars on ggplot2 (overlaying background panel)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use some good practice examples suggested on my ggplot2 graphs, but one thing I am stuck with is how to move the x axis text closer to the bars. Here is what I mean:

```
car.names <- rownames(mtcars)    
qplot(car.names[1:3],mtcars$wt[1:3],geom="bar",stat="identity") + geom_text(aes(y=mtcars$wt[1:3]),label=paste(mtcars$wt[1:3]),size=10,hjust=0.54,vjust=1.5,color="white")
```

If i use this code, this is the plot I will get:

[image]

Great! I can see the text.axis (Datsun 710, etc) are aligned with this grey background. But now consider the following function that edits out the grid along with some adjustment for the text size, etc:

```
 science_theme = theme(
    panel.background=element_blank(), 
    axis.line=element_blank(),
    text = element_text(size=25, family="Interstate",colour='grey'),
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5,vjust=0.3, size=25), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Now I call the same function with my new theme:

```
qplot(car.names[1:3],mtcars$wt[1:3],geom="bar",stat="identity") + geom_text(aes(y=mtcars$wt[1:3]),label=paste(mtcars$wt[1:3]),size=10,hjust=0.54,vjust=1.5,color="white") + science_theme
```

And this is what I get next:

[image]

Spiffy. The problem however is the annoying white space between the bars and the labels now. I expected that in setting element_blanks() the plot would understand the grey region is no longer there and therefore push it upwards.

I've attempted using vjust on the axis.text alignment but it doesn't move anywhere. [I also looked at this page](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/) which details more each element, but couldn't get it moving.

Any ideas? Just to make sure you understand my question: The correct plot will look like the last, aside that the x axis names (i.e. Datsun 710, etc.) will be closer to the bars. Same for the y axis.

Comment: Did you play with `expand` argument of `scale_y_continuous`? Or something like this.

Comment: wasnt aware of it, so no. i will try it now, but if you think this solves the problem with the self contained example please put it as answer so i can properly reward the solution :)

Comment: Well, since I upgraded my version of `ggplot2`, your example doesn't work for me.

Comment: I see. Can you please still post as an answer? adding + scale_y_discrete(expand=c(-0.5,0)) solved the problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `expand` argument of `scale_y_discrete`:

```
qplot(car.names[1:3],mtcars$wt[1:3],geom="bar",stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(y=mtcars$wt[1:3]),label=paste(mtcars$wt[1:3]),size=10,hjust=0.54,vjust=1.5,color="white") + 
  science_theme +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(-0.5,0))
```

[image]